# Complexity of Nested for Loops

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to figure out the time of my algorithm, using Big O notation, and I couldn't find a quite clear explanation about it.

Basically, my algorithm consists in comparing a new array to all other arrays in a "parent" array.

For that, I have a for loop, that iterates all elements in the parent array, looking for an array that looks like the newly created array.

Here's the code:

```
bool AlreadyExistingArray(Array array)
{
    bool areEqual = true;
    foreach (Array a in arrayEntries)
    {
        if (a.count != array.count)
            continue;

        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            if (!a.contains(i))
            {
                areEqual = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (areEqual)
        {
            areEqual = false;
            foreach (int i in a)
            {
                if (!a.contains(i))
                {
                    areEqual = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return areEqual;
}
```

I understand that each of the for loops should be a O(n), however, should the complexity be composed? Since I'm dealing with different sized arrays, I'm quite sure the complexity cannot be considered O(n^2).

Hope I made myself clear! Otherwise, let me know and I'll try and clarify even further.

Edit: changed algorithm.

Comment: The contains method itself is an O(n) operation. Your algorithm looks closer to O(n^3) for an n x n matrix

Comment: even though the sizes of the arrays are different?

Comment: Your function can be simplified to `foreach (Array a in arrayEntries) { if (a.count == array.count) { return false; } } return true;`.

Comment: It all depends on what is variable in this algorithm. Apparently `arrayEntries` is a global variable, and can not be influenced by the function call, so one could argue that it is fixed. In that case it just represents a constant factor in the time complexity, and so the algorithm is *O(n)*

Comment: @gowrath So, basically, the array is provided by the user. I don't know how many entries it will contain. The arrayEntries can scale up to infinite, since each user input is an entry. So, your k variable is not making much sense, to me. Could you explain it any further?

Comment: @NicolasReichert See answer below.

Comment: Part of your problem is that you keep talking about `n`.  But your algorithm has no `n` in it.

Comment: @NicolasReichert Your `if (a.count != array.count)` should be a `continue`  not a `return false`.

Answer (score 6):

## A Little Background on Big-Oh:

The reason you are getting so many varying answers here is that Big-O analysis is not as simple as just counting the number of steps the program runs. This simplified version which is taught to Computer Scientists is an approximation (that is usually sufficient) of the concept of Big-O, Big-Omega, and Big-Theta asymptotic bounds of functions. There is actually a [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of Big-O which would eradicate these ambiguities.

Nevertheless, let us persist. My answer from the comments was such:

> Call the size of arrayEntries: `len(arrayEntries) = n` and the size of array `len(array) = m` and the size of the largest entry in array `len(largestOfarray) = k` (that is the size of the largest variable you call **a**). Then your algorithm is O(n(m+k)). Whichever one of n,m, or k are constants that will never change size, just remove them from that equation.

Let me explain the above. The definition of Big-O is roughly:

> In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms by how they respond to changes in input size, such as how the processing time of an algorithm changes as the problem size becomes extremely large.

When you say an algorithm is `O(n^2)`, what this means is this. You are saying that the runtime of your algorithm can be denoted as some function `T(n)` (note it only has one variable n) and asymptotically `T(n)` grown no faster than `n^2` (that is, very roughly, as n gets very large, the gradient of the function `f(n) = n^2` at n will be bigger than the gradient of T(n) at n).

Now in the previous example, the runtime of the algorithm depended on one variable n. This is not always the case. Imagine you have a program like this:

```
void algorithm(Array arrayM, Array arrayN) {
    for(int i : arrayN) {
        // runs len(arrayN) = n times
    }
    for(int j : arrayM) {
        // runs len(arrayM) = m times
    }
}
```

The runtime of this algorithm is a function that depends on the size of arrayM and arrayN so it would be denoted `T(n,m)`. Now if these sizes are independent variables (i.e. the size of arrayM has no relation to the size of arrayN), then the runtime of this algorithm is `O(m+n)`. However, if the size of arrayM did depend on the size of arrayN (say it was initialized by copying half the elements of arrayN into it), then `len(arrayM) = m` actually depends on n such `m = n/2`. Thus your algorithm's time complexity which was previously `O(m+n)`, is now `O(n+n/2) = O(n)`. This is intrinsically because your runtime function `T(n,m)` can now be written as `T(n, n/2) ~ T(n)` i.e. it is a function of one variable.

## Your Specific Example:

Now in the case of your program, initially let us assume that the size of **arrayEntries** `len(arrayEntries) = n` and the size of **array** `len(array) = m` and the size of the largest entry in **array** (the largest possible **a**) `len(largestOfarray) = k`, are completely independent variables that don't depend on each other. This is not an unreasonable assumption since you said in one of your comments that "the inner loops do not depend on any value of the outter one" since it is number of user inputs and the length of the input might be arbitrarily long as one user might input something of length 1 and another user might input a line 1000 characters long.

Since n, m, and k are independent, your complexity is thus. Your outer loop runs n times and within each iteration, the first inner loop will run m times and the second one will at worst run k times. Thus your total complexity is `O(n(m+k))`. But is that all? Well not quite.

See there are some bounds to n,m, and k. Namely, that the length of the user input (k) probably has a limit (i.e. if it is being taken from stdin, then it probably won't be longer than 1000 chars). If so, you could reasonably say that the worst k could be is 1000 and so we can treat it like a constant and then the complexity of your algorithm is `O(nm)` because the constant k is eradicated. This step depends wholly on how you think your program will be used but if you want to be safe, you could just say the complexity is `O(n(m+k))`.

This does however beg the question, could one not reason that m and n are also bounded because there is a limit on how large they can be (namely how much memory your operating system will allocate to your program) and thus be treated as constants? Well technically, yes. And in some algorithmic analyses, this is a useful thing to do sometimes (such as in the case of slow growing algorithms).

Ultimately it all depends on how you think your program would work and what are reasonable assumptions to make (i.e. k can be considered a constant) and which ones to avoid. In my personal opinion, this algorithm would be `O(n(m+k))` and possibly `O(nm)` but I wouldn't cut it more than that; m and n seem pretty independent from your descriptions.

## Important Edit (answer above is not correct after your code edit):

An interesting case study actually is what was commented to this answer below by @frenzykryger; a detail I missed out because you edited your question while I was writing the answer. The commenter said that you changed the start of your outer loop to check if the size of **a** is equal to the size of **array**. This means the number of times your second inner loop will run (i.e. the size of k as described above) now depends completely on m (recall m was the size of array), namely k = m. Thus your algorithm is `O(n(m+m)) = O(nm)`. Now if you are guaranteed that m is always less than n, then the algorithm would be `O(n^2)` (the m can be discarded). But if m is unbounded (could be any size), then the algorithm remains `O(nm)`.

## Final Remarks:

As you can see, Big-Oh analysis is something that sometimes doesn't have a single right answer. It all depends on how your program will behave, what sort of inputs you are guaranteed to get, and many other factors. If all this makes you wish there were a more rigorous way to define it, there certainly is - just google "Big-Oh formal definition", read some links, head on over to mathematics stack exchange, and you'll have yourself a guaranteed party.

Comment: OP added size check before actually comparing arrays, wouldn't that eliminate variable `k` completely?

Comment: @frenzykryger Do you meant the ` if (a.count != array.count) return false;`?

Comment: @frenzykryger I'm not familiar with the pseudocode language used by op. If count is the size of the arrays, you're right. I'll fix the answer :)

Comment: yep, previously there was `continue` instead of `return false`, just stopping when there is mismatch in array lengths doesn't seem to be right thing to do.

Comment: Now, that's a brilliant answer. Thank you so much, @gowrath!

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation is concerned with computational growth as the size of your application changes. Thus there are three key questions here that will determine the big-O notation, all are related to how your application scales:

1. As your application scales, does the number of elements in your "new
   array" grow? In other words, early in the life of your application,
   might there be 20 elements in this "new array" but as the
   application has more users (or data or whatever), might the count
   grow to *n* elements?
2. As your application scales, does the number
   **arrays** of "all other arrays in the 'parent' array" grow? Could it go from comparing one array to two other arrays (as your code
   above shows) to comparing one array to *n* other arrays?
3. As your
   application scales, does the number of **elements** in "all the
   other arrays in the 'parent' array" grow? In other words, when
   comparing to these other arrays, could each other array go from
   containing, say, 20 elements to containing *n* elements?

Count the number of "yes" answers to the questions above. They represent your *n*'s. Three "yes" answers indicates *O(n^3)*.

**A bit more on Big O.** As counter-intuitive as it may seem, comparing an array with 500 elements to another array of 500 elements, if neither array ever changes, has a time complexity of *O(1)*. Even though 25,000 comparisons must be made, since the number of comparisons never changes, the complexity reduces to 1. This begins to make sense when you start to imagine the possibilities for caching results, sorting, or choosing very efficient data structures or search algorithms.

Now imagine checking a document of variable size against a document of fixed size (e.g. a spell checker checks a document against all 171,000 words in the Oxford English Dictionary). The document has *n* words, but surely the 171,000 words in the OED must have some impact on the time complexity?

Actually, no. The complexity would be *O(n)*, because the only variable is the size of the document. This also begins to make sense when you read about some data structures that make word lookup *very* fast against a known word list (e.g. a Trie). The time to check a document scales linearly with the size of the document.

We would get *O(n^2)* complexity if we were comparing, say, a document of size *n* against another document of size *n*. In this case, comparing two documents of size 1000 would not scale linearly when the document size increases to 10,000,000,000; if the size of the documents was a variable expected to grow, we would likely have to rethink our approach.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's clear, but, the arrays are from different constitution. The outter loop is going through an array of arrays. Then, each of the arrays can have few entries. 

However, the amount of entries in this arrays are not scalable, as each array is provided by the user. It can have 10 entries, 1 entry, or even 1000 entries. 

Will this affect your answer?

Comment: You still should be able to answer your question by counting your "yes" answers above. To help you clarify, ask yourself what changes when you go from 10 users to 10,000,000. If I am understanding you correctly, the count of arrays is directly related to the number of users in the system, but the count of elements in each array, though variable, will likely have an average value? (Think blog post length: variable, but has a stable average.)

Comment: I understand. It's just that I really don't have a way to predict how long would an array provided by the user be. Although they are not scaling, nor constant. In that case, should I disregard them from the equation or should I consider, as other have suggested, O(n(k+m))?

Answer (score 1):

Number of operations in worst case is what matters for time complexity of the algorithm, so loops are indeed hints but it's not necessary that two nested loops mean answer is *O(n²)*. Worst case for your algorithm is when your array is equal to last array in `arrayEntries` and is almost equal (except the last element) to all other arrays in `arrayEntries`. Let *N* be number of arrays in `arrayEntries`, *M* be number of elements in `array`, let `array.contains` complexity be *O(M)*. It is *O(M)* because it's array, so I assume that simple linear search is used. If you will replace array with a hash set, then `array.contains` complexity will be amortized *O(1)*. If you pre-sort arrays and will use binary search then complexity will be just *O(log M)* - same if you will use some tree set. Data structure you use actually affect asymptotic of your algorithm.

```
bool AlreadyExistingArray(Array array)
{
    bool areEqual = true;
    foreach (Array a in arrayEntries) // Loop executes N times
    {
        if (a.count != array.count)
            continue;

        foreach (int i in array) // Loop executes M times
        {
            if (!a.contains(i)) // has O(M) complexity because a.count == array.count here
            {
                areEqual = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (areEqual)
        {
            areEqual = false;
            foreach (int i in a) // executes M times
            {
                if (!array.contains(i)) // has O(M) complexity
                {
                    areEqual = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return areEqual;
}
```

Here you got loop in another loop which calls operation which costs *O(M)*.
So complexity is like:

*N · M · O(M) + M · O(M) = O (N · M²)*.

It will execute first nested loop *N* times giving *N · M · O(M)* and then execute second loop when `areEqual` becomes true giving *M · O(M)*. We are only interested in "highest" term here, so we can throw away last *M · O(M)* and this gives answer *O (N · M²)* 
If length of `arrayEntries` is constant, then complexity is *O(M²)*. If length of `array` is constant, then complexity is *O(N)*.

There are some algorithms with *O(n)* complexity which are expressed by nested loops, so don't forget to calculate number of operations, not just loops. It is important to seek most hard cases for algorithm because asymptotic can actually be different in "common" case and "hard" case. Usual example is quicksort algorithm - it's asymptotic on most of inputs is *O(n log n)* but it's *O(n²)* in case when array is already sorted. Even if your algorithm has same asymptotic on every input - it's easier to reason about it in "hard" case because this is where it's runtime is maximized and approaches its asymptotic bound. For example, your algorithm will work with *O(M²)* complexity for any *N* if first array from `arrayEntries` is the one which is equal to `array`. But this doesn't mean that overall complexity of algorithm is *O(M²)* for any *N*.

Find and read [Cormen's introduction to algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) book if you want to have good knowledge on algorithms. First chapter has introduction in big-O notation applied to analysis of different algorithms.

Comment: Big O is concerned with asymptotic growth. So the size of elements in each array is immaterial to time complexity if none of them will grow in size. Big O is only concerned with size as it approaches infinity, so if none of the arrays will approach infinity as the application scales, the time complexity is O(1).

Comment: Yep, I've wrote that it either of parameters is constant, then complexity changes. True, if both of them are constant then it's O(1) but there is no much point in calculating complexity if all is constant.

Answer (score 0):

To under in better way lets take one example:

You have doubly nested loops, and the outer loop is dependent on the problem size n,but the inner loop is dependent on the
current value of the index variable of the outer loop

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
     for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
     // these statements are executed O(n^2) times
     }
}
```

Let's analyze this case iteration‐by‐iteration:
On the 1st iteration of the outer loop (i = 0), the inner loop will iterate 0 times
On the 2nd iteration of the outer loop (i = 1), the inner loop will iterate 1 time
On the 3rd iteration of the outer loop (i = 2), the inner loop will iterate 2 times

.

.

On the FINAL iteration of the outer loop (i = n ‐ 1), the inner loop will
iterate n ‐ 1 times

So, the total number of times the statements in the inner loop will be executed
will be equal to the sum of the integers from 1 to n ‐ 1, which is:

((n ‐ 1)*n) / 2 = n^2/2 ‐ n/2 = O(n^2) times

So in your case the complexity is O(n(k+m)) = O(n(n+n)) = O(n^2) times;

where

```
  n -> arrayentries size
  k -> array size
  m -> a size
```

This is becasuse Big-O notation isn't about finding exact values given your actual parameters. It is about determining asymptotic runtime.

Comment: the problem is that the inner loops do not depend on any value of the outter one. They are completely different sets of arrays. I can have an array of arrays with 1000 arrays, each one containing less than 10 entries.

Comment: @Mahendra Thapa, you're right that Big O is concerned with asymptotic growth, which means "as a variable approaches infinity." In your explanation we must figure out which of *n*, *k*, and *m* will approach infinity as the application scales. Without knowing that, we can't know whether the algorithm has a complexity of *O(1)* or *O(n^3)*.

Comment: @NicolasReichert,  foreach (Array **a** in arrayEntries){
            foreach (int i in  **a**)
            {
            }
        }

Comment: @jakeblues if n or k or m equals to _infinity_ , then the Big-O complexity of an infinite loop is **undefined** (as much as i know)

Comment: @Mahendra Thapa: Not an infinite loop. Variables that "approach infinity" is math terminology for unbounded growth. For example, the total number of pictures uploaded to Facebook is a variable that (as far as we can tell from here) has unbounded growth.