# Need to find Big of the code with Order and Order Details

Tags: java, c#, big-o

I know the Big O of nested loop is n^2. But what if the nested loop not depend upon n. Will it be n* k. Lets say we have users and for each user we have to find his courses. Another example, suppose we id. From id we have to find all the orders and from each order we have to find all order details.

```
public static void DoSomeStuff(string id)
{
    // find all orders from id
    for (int i = 0; i < orders.Count; i++)
    {
        var order = orders[i];
        // find orderDetails from Order
        for (int j = 0; j < orderDetails.Count; j++)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

What's the BIg O here?

Comment: You are right. The answer is  O(n*m). n is size of orders and m is size of the biggest orderDetails.

Comment: Related Question: [Complexity of Nested For Loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181854/complexity-of-nested-for-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `// Do something` runs in `O(1)`, your code is in `O(orders.Count * orderDetails.Count)`.

Comment: Define `n` and `m`.

Comment: By "something extraordinary" you mean something O(1)? :)

Comment: orders.Count = n and orderDetails.Count = m :). So n * m?

Comment: @Max, no `O(1)` is the case for which the above analysis holds, but if it contains a couple more nested `for`-loops or so, then we're screwed. :) -- I guess I should clarify that in the answer.

Comment: @user960567 With `orders.Count = n` and `orderDetails.Count = m`, `O(orders.Count * orderDetails.Count) = O(n * m)` by definition, so yes! :)